# mongodb version 3.0.0 client robomongo mongovue

Tags: mongodb, mongovue, robo3t

We are using mongo client tools such as Robomongo and MongoVUE from our windows/mac machines. On the mongodb server side, we decided to try out the new MongoDB 3.0.0rc8 with wiredtiger storage. However, we find that we are not able to list any collections from our client tools and mongo shell. If we login to the server box running mongodb, and then start a mongo shell, then we are able to view the collections.
Is this a known problem - that the existing tools like Robomongo and MongoVUE which have been supporting up to 2.6.X are not yet supporting mongodb 3.0.0? 
Is there any mongo client that supports version 3.0.0?

Thanks and Regards,
Archanaa Panda

Comment: It is June 2016, and MongoVue has still not been updated to read catalogs from a MongoDB 3+ instance.   I have tried to contact the developer, but received no response.

Answer (score 12):

We encountered the same issue today and started evaluating MongoChef http://3t.io/mongochef which looks promising, both seen to UI, features and support for WiredTiger.

Comment: I have just tried mongochef and I have to say that is IMO better than MongoVUE and also supports WiredTiger. Great find!

Comment: Unfortunately mongochef is not free to use commercially, and subscriptions are not that cheap :(. Nowadays robomongo seems a pretty good alternative, however with less features than mongochef (no export/import, no querybuilder, etc)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer to this question i got on google forums from Will Berkeley-

> Yes, those tools need to be updated to support 3.0 on WiredTiger. Many
>   tools enumerate namespaces by querying system collections that do not
>   exist when MongoDB is running WiredTiger. The mongo shell function
>   db.getCollectionNames() and the show command pre-3.0 does this, too -
>   the reason you can list collections on the 3.0 mongod box is that you
>   have the 3.0 mongo shell installed there.
>
> -Will

Answer (score 4):

I use [NoSQL Manager for MongoDB](http://www.mongodbmanager.com/) with Mongo 3.0/WiredTiger

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed as of February 1, 2016 with [Robomongo](http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-rc4/).

Answer (score 0):

Using the right version that is robomongo-0.9.0-rc8 fixed my problem.