# MongoDB WiredTiger issue

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I have work a lot with MongoDB 2.6, then I decide to start using MongoDB 3.0.2.

1) When I create an Database using the shell command, the command return true but
   the database is not created.
   use NewDatabaseName
2) When i try to create some collections, sometime is created and sometime no

I'm using Debian 64Bit, latest version.
Anybody is having this issue?

Comment: Is this a fresh install of mongo?

Comment: Try inserting a collection and data, database and collection creation is lazy

Comment: yes, is an fresh install totally.

Comment: Please show us the commands you're using and what they return. How do you try to create databases and collections? How do you know they aren't created?

Comment: ./mongod --port 8080 --noauth --dbpath ./data2 -storageEngine wiredTiger

Comment: use NewDatabaseName (in order to create a New Database).

Comment: response "switched to db NewDatabaseName"

Comment: db.createCollection('myCollection');

Comment: if i use "show dbs" i can see the new database. But from my editor (MongoVUE, and also many other already compatible with WiredTiger) i'm not able to see the collection.

Comment: i start to think that is something related to the editor. Because with MongoDB Management Studio everything work fine.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 3.0 is not compatible with all GUI.
For example today MongoVUE do not work at all.

But MongoDB Management Studio sounds like the only one that really work.

Also here some other post related.
[mongodb version 3.0.0 client robomongo mongovue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637624/mongodb-version-3-0-0-client-robomongo-mongovue)

Answer (score 0):

Yes your problem is GUI-related. You can check out different tools on this page:

http://mongodb-tools.com/

I will most probably be using MongoChef from now on.