# How to start using MongoDB and MongoVue?

Tags: asp.net, windows, mongodb, mongovue

I am just trying to learn MongoDB. I followed this walktrough to install it:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Here is my screenshot for mongod.exe:

[image: mongod.exe]

And here isthe screenshot of mongo.exe:

[image: mongo.exe]

It seems everything is fine to me. Am I wrong?

During my googlings I decided that MongoVue is a good management application for MongoDB by a cool user interface. So I downloaded and installed it. Here is the screen I see when I opened it:

[image: mongovue]

How do I have to fill these fields to create a connection from MongoVue to MongoDB? Do I have to do something else before that?

Comment: Maybe you should slow down a bit and read something. How did you plan to use it if you can't even figure out what server you installed it on? How were you planning to use it in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you haven't configured authentication within MongoDB, just give the connection a name and fill in the IP address of the server (127.0.0.1 if it's local):

[image: Connection Dialog]

Click `Test` to test out the settings and then `Save` to create the connection.  Then click `Connect` on the parent dialog to actually connect to the server.

**Caution**

MongoVUE doesn't work with 3.x MongoDB servers and hasn't been updated in almost two years. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637624/mongodb-version-3-0-0-client-robomongo-mongovue) for alternatives.

Comment: I did all this and it connects fine and shows me there's one collection and the number of elements inside of it but I can't view the collection. Almost all menu elements are grayed out. Any ideas why I can't even get started?

Comment: MongoVue doesn't support 3.x MongoDB servers and its development appears dead as they haven't released a new version in almost two years. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637624/mongodb-version-3-0-0-client-robomongo-mongovue

Comment: That clears it up then. Thank you! Do you happen to have a recommendation for a Mongo GUI that does support 3.2? I just clicked the link, will check out MongoChef. If you have other recommendations I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @McAdam331 There are a couple mentioned in the answers to the question I linked to. Give them a try.