# Failed to connect MongoDB 3.X with MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

I am running MongoDB on windows8.1 and created users for admin database. For convenience, I use mongoVUE to check data. But after turning on the "auth" function. I cannot logged in.

Actually, I can use the username and password to authenticate with mongo shell. Further more, I can also use them to authenticate by python codes. They failed to work only when I use mongoVUE or Robomongo.

When I clicked "test" button on mongoVUE, it returned a message "Connection was refused". And the windows command shell presents the following words:

> 2015-07-03T19:52:34.843+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection
>   accepted from
>    127.0.0.1:24163 #242 (4 connections now open)
>
> 2015-07-03T19:52:34.845+0800 I ACCESS   [conn242]  authenticate db:
>   admin { auth enticate: 1, user: "uvpaiad", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
>
> 2015-07-03T19:52:34.846+0800 I ACCESS   [conn242] Failed to
>   authenticate uvpaiad @admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR:
>   AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials mi ssing in the user
>   document
>
> 2015-07-03T19:52:34.847+0800 I NETWORK  [conn242] end connection
>   127.0.0.1:24163  (3 connections now open)

Does anyone know what the matter is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb version 3.0.0 client robomongo mongovue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637624/mongodb-version-3-0-0-client-robomongo-mongovue)

Comment: robomongo and mongovue cannot support mangodb 3.0 now?

Comment: "Authentication" is the key. The [Mechanism](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#authentication-mechanisms) changed in MongoDB 3.x series, so any client that does not support SCRAM-SHA-1 cannot connect (using authentication). The recommendation is to "update drivers" but the products mentioned have current build problems preventing this change.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the changed authentication mechanism in MongoDB latest version. In Mongo 3.X, auth mechanism is changed to SCRAM- Salted challenge response authentication mechanism.

In order to avoid this one needs to get into system users collection and create the new users documents and delete the old ones.