# MongoDB GUI Suggestions (MongoHub and RoboMongo)

Tags: mongodb

I am a beginner to MongoDB. Using Mongo version 3.2.6. I usually use the mongo terminal from the shell. To get a deeper understanding visually I tried using a GUI but I am finding no luck in it. Initially I tried using RoboMongo, the issue is even though I get connected at 127.0.0.1:27017 I am not able to view the collection items. I also have authentication issues with both RoboMongo and MongoHub. Please suggest the best GUI for learning MongoDB

Thanks in advance

Comment: RoboMongo is working for me perfectly. I don't know why you can't view collection items. However, I use an older version of mongodb. I would suggest trying MongoChef.

Comment: try using robomongo-0.9.0-rc8..

Comment: Is authentication mandatory to see collection items in robo mongo ?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637624/mongodb-version-3-0-0-client-robomongo-mongovue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ user3632894 Thank you so much. Using the  robomongo-0.9.0-rc8 fixed my problem.